# Lumen Reset Password not working - can't find token

Tags: php, lumen

I'm trying to implement the ability to reset a user's password in Lumen 5.6. I am build an API with Lumen and then using Angular for the front end.

The first step to receive the email link works fine, but when a user actually tries to reset their password it does not work and the invalid token error is returned, but a token is there in the database (although the token is hashed).

Might this be an issue with the token hashing?

**This is my code for the "reset" method in the ResetsPassword.php trait:**

```
public function reset(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'token' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6'
        ]);

        $credentials = $request->only('token', 'email', 'password', 'password_confirmation');

        $broker = $this->getBroker();
        $response = Password::broker($broker)->reset($credentials, function ($user, $password) {
            $this->resetPassword($user, $password);
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::PASSWORD_RESET:
                return $this->getResetSuccessResponse($response);

            default:
                return $this->getResetFailureResponse($request, $response);
        }
    }
```